# Generate Minified CSS from SCSS from WEB PACK and Laravel 5.5.2

Tags: css, laravel-5, webpack, sass, minify

**Todo :**

- Generate the minified CSS files from SCSS file using Web Pack
- Is there any command which did that??. 
  it's like **when I compiled my SCSS it should generate the minified CSS**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you take a look at Laravel mix? It is a wrapper around Webpack.

Default Mix behavior minifies the css for you if you run `npm run production`. Is that enough to solve your problem? Otherwise, please be more specific in your question. And show us what you have tried. Put some effort in your question.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#working-with-stylesheets

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1295

Comment: i have used npm run dev which compile SCSS into CSS

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
npm run production
```